# web.xml order or filter and listener

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-listeners

For a Java EE web application,
I have a listener that implements ServletRequestListener, and a Filter.

Is there a way to specify at web.xml that the filter should be called before the listener?

I've already tried declaring the filter and its mapping before the listener,
but the listener is still executed before.

Any idea?

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>myfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.MyFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myfilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.MyServletRequestListener </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Answer (score 12):

When Browser(client) request to the Server , the container like (Tomcat) create the Request Object for the client request  HttpServletRequest and Response Object HttpServletResponse and 
if you configure any listener which implements "ServletRequestListener" then "public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre)" method will call

After creation of Request and Response Object by container if there is any listener for Request then Listener  will execute first.....

After that HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse  are assign to the Fillter , if you have configure  the Fillter....

Means Listener come in picture first for ServletRequest .
So there is no way to configure to make Fillter execute before Listener in ServletRequest case ....

Answer (score 5):

The     `ServletRequestListener.requestInitialized()` will be initialized before any filter is invoked and `ServletRequestListener.requestDestroyed()` after all filter and service method returns.

Comment: so, it is not possible to have the filter.doFilter() executed before a listener.requestInitialized()? i am reading the servlet 2.5 spec, but i don't find this info. http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-2.5-mrel2-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-2_5-mrel2-spec.pdf   where is this explained?