# How should a scoped bean trigger session creation in Hazelcast

Tags: java, spring, session, hazelcast, oauth-2.0

I am using spring-web (4.1.7) with spring-security-oauth2 (2.0.12) and hazelcast (3.3).

While testing this a user (with no session) visits the site and clicks on the link to start OpenId Connect login.

I have added a HttpSessionListener to check when the session is created.

The OAuth2RestTemplate is used to perform authentication and contains this line:
OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = context.getAccessToken();

The context object is a OAuth2ClientContext bean with session scope and it seems that using this object (not instantiating it) triggers creation of a session (and the context is stored in the session).

So far so good, however the problem I have is that I am using Hazelcast for session replication and no Hazelcast session gets created.  This is a problem because when the request finishes and no Hazelcast session is found for the HttpSession then the Hazelcast filter will destroy the HttpSession.

My question is, how should creation of a Hazelcast filter be triggered ?
The stacktrace for creating the session shows that we do not make any call to Hazelcast to create the session:

```
WebSessionListener.sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent) line: 15    
StandardSession.tellNew() line: 367 
StandardSession.setId(String) line: 341 
StandardManager(ManagerBase).createSession(String) line: 857    
StandardManager.createSession(String) line: 291 
Request.doGetSession(boolean) line: 2606    
Request.getSession(boolean) line: 2316  
RequestFacade.getSession(boolean) line: 841 
ServletRequestAttributes.getSession(boolean) line: 111  
ServletRequestAttributes.getSessionMutex() line: 244    
SessionScope.get(String, ObjectFactory<?>) line: 91 
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).doGetBean(String, Class<T>, Object[], boolean) line: 337    
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).getBean(String) line: 194   
SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget() line: 35 
JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 187   
$Proxy322.getAccessToken() line: not available  
OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken() line: 169
```

I have some some hacking and found that if I put in a call to
request.getSession(true);
This will create the both

1. the HttpSession
2. The Hazelcast Session

The stack trace shows we go through the Hazelcast method SpringAwareWebFilter.createNewSession before creating the HttpSession.

So the issue I have seems to be:

When using a RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequestWrapper).getSession()
to get/create a session this is Hazelcast aware.

However when spring tries to create a session (triggered when a session scoped bean is used), it is not Hazelcast aware.

Is this expected behaviour i.e. spring does not know to create the Hazelcast session and I have to find some workaround ?  Or can anyone recommend any further way to debug this ?

In web.xml the hazelcast config is:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hazelcast-filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.hazelcast.web.spring.SpringAwareWebFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>map-name</param-name>
            <param-value>sessions</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>sticky-session</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cookie-name</param-name>
            <param-value>hazelcast.session</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cookie-secure</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cookie-http-only</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>config-location</param-name>
            <param-value>hazelcast-geneva.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>


        <init-param>
            <param-name>shutdown-on-destroy</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hazelcast-filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

For reference, if I force a call to request.getSession and this call goes through the Hazelcast filters WebFilter and SpringAwareWebFilter the stack chain is like this (compare to the stack above where the Hazelcast filters are missing)

```
WebSessionListener.sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent) line: 15    
StandardSession.tellNew() line: 367 
StandardSession.setId(String) line: 341 
StandardManager(ManagerBase).createSession(String) line: 857    
StandardManager.createSession(String) line: 291 
Request.doGetSession(boolean) line: 2606    
Request.getSession(boolean) line: 2316  
RequestFacade.getSession(boolean) line: 841 
WebFilter$RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequestWrapper).getSession(boolean) line: 255   
WebFilter$RequestWrapper.getOriginalSession(boolean) line: 533  
SpringAwareWebFilter(WebFilter).createNewSession(WebFilter$RequestWrapper, String) line: 307    
SpringAwareWebFilter.createNewSession(WebFilter$RequestWrapper, String) line: 47    
WebFilter$RequestWrapper.getSession(boolean) line: 605  
WebFilter$RequestWrapper.getSession(boolean) line: 515  
RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequestWrapper).getSession(boolean) line: 255
```

## Update

I found that when a method is called on my session scoped bean that it triggers a call to ServletRequestAttributes.getSession(boolean).

This object has an attribute called request on which it calls getSession(boolean).
If this request object was the WebFilter$RequestWrapper created by the Hazelcast filter, this I suspect everything would work fine.

However ServletRequestAttributes is initialised with a HttpServletRequest (not wrapped by Hazelcast) well before the Hazelcast filter doFilter is called.

It does not seem possible to update the request attribute in ServletRequestAttributes, but maybe there is some way to create a new one.

## Update 2

I was using RequestContextListener, it gets triggered before any of the filters and sets the request object in ServletRequestAttributes before the Hazelcast filter has a chance to wrap it.  I removed RequestContextListener and replaced it with RequestContextFilter (as seems to be what they did in spring boot: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2637).  This makes sure when ServletRequestAttributes is initialized, it gets the Hazelcast request object.

Comment: I assume you're using hazelcast-wm. Can you share how you define Hazelcast WebFilter - your web.xml or your initializer code?

Comment: Do you use `WebFilter` or `SpringAwareWebFilter`?

Comment: Hi @emre, I was originally using WebFilter and an older version of hazelcast-wm which did not have SpringAwareWebFilter.  Now that I use SpringAwareWebFilter, the Hazelcast session did not get created when I expected, but I do not have a hazelcast cookie.  Let me double check that I have observed this correctly, but using SpringAwareWebFilter seems to have fixed this

Comment: It only works if I add in a call to explicitly create a session before the scoped variable is used (request.getScope(true)).  When I remove this hack spring does not create the hazelcast session when the session scoped variable is used.  It seems maybe that SpringAwareWebFilter does its best to create a spring session when there is a hazelcast session, but nothing in spring to create a hazelcast session when a HttpSession is created.

Comment: Hazelcast's `WebFilter` (and `SpringAwareFilter` also) creates a `RequestWrapper`. When you call `request.getSession()`, a new `HazelcastSession` is created, or the existing one is returned if any. That's why the README says `Make sure Hazelcast filter is placed before all the other filters if any; you can put it at the top.` Do you have your filter definition before all the other filters?

Comment: Yes, SpringAwareWebFilter is at the top of my stack, before DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate starts to kick off the calls to my springSecurityFilterChain.  When I force a call to request.getSession(boolean), I can see the stack chain go through WebFilter and SpringAwareWebFilter.  However when I use a session scoped bean and this triggers creation of the session, those Hazelcast filters are missing

Comment: @emre, you were correct to say make sure Hazelcast filter is placed before all other filters.  I figured out that my problem was the use of RequestContextListener, it gets triggered before any other filters.  I removed this and used RequestContextFilter instead and when it gets called ServletRequestAttributes gets initialized with the correct wrapper request object.  If you summarize your comments as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hazelcast `WebFilter` (and `SpringAwareFilter` as well) wraps the request in a `RequestWrapper`. When `request.getSession()` is called, the wrapper creates a new `HazelcastSession`, or returns the existing one if there's any.

That's why `WebFilter` needs to be defined before other filters. From  [hazelcast-wm's README](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-wm#setting-up-session-clustering):

> Make sure Hazelcast filter is placed before all the other filters if any; you can put it at the top.

Servlet containers process `ServletRequestListener` instances before filters (see [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11257533/2080975)). So, if the `ServletRequestListener` (or any other code piece) invokes `request.getSession()` before `WebFilter` has a chance to wrap the request, no `HazelcastSession` will be created and session replication won't work.

Making sure Hazelcast `WebFilter` wraps the request before any calls to `request.getSession()` solves the problem.